# i don't now how use background from js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a newbie to js and I would like to know how you can use background from javascript let's say I can set the color of a button by doing this:

```
const btnPulsado = (e) =>{
const btn= e.target;
btn.style.backgroundColor= 'red';
```

can I do it somehow with backgroundImage?

Comment: yes you can `btn.style.backgroundImage = "url(path)"` or `btn.style["background-image"] = "url(path)"` please search first before asking

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
e.target.style.backgroundColor = __ANY_COLOR_CODE;
```

```js
function genRanHex(size) {
  return [...Array(size)].map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16)).join('')
}

const btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = `#${genRanHex(6)}`;
})
```

```html
<button> click me to change color </button>
```